# Additional Security for Files & Directories

Tags: linux, permissions

I am running Lynis 3.0.3 on Debian 10, and it gives me warnings (FILE-7524) about files and directories.  Below are two examples:

```
/etc/crontab   are not matching expected value (644 != rw-------)
/etc/cron.d are not matching expected value (755 != rwx------)
```

Meanwhile, when I run stat on the file and directory listed above, I get:

```
# stat /etc/crontab
  File: /etc/crontab
  Size: 1042        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 393415      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2021-05-12 22:23:14.716000000 +0800
Modify: 2019-03-11 00:49:18.000000000 +0800
Change: 2021-05-13 08:55:08.491989031 +0800
 Birth: -
```

And,

```
# stat /etc/cron.d/ 
  File: /etc/cron.d/
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 393406      Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2021-05-12 22:23:14.776000000 +0800
Modify: 2021-05-11 17:25:46.922661825 +0800
Change: 2021-05-11 17:25:46.922661825 +0800
 Birth: -
```

So question(s) fundamentally are:

1.) How do I change (0644/-rw-r--r--) & (0755/drwxr-xr-x) to (644 != rw-------) & (755 != rwx------), respectively.

And,

2. Other than adding additional security the relevant files & directories, what, if any, are downsides / possible negative impacts that I need to consider?

(NOTE: I am the sole root user / administrator for the server )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I change (0644/-rw-r--r--) & (0755/drwxr-xr-x) to (644 != rw-------) & (755 != rwx------), respectively.

Use the `chmod` command.

Currently the file and the directory are world-readable (they have +rx in all three groups – owner, group, and world). Lynis suggests making them only readable to their owner (which is likely 'root'), which means removing 'r' and 'x' from group/world, which can be set using `go-rx` or `g-rx,o-rx` or `g=,o=` or several other ways.

The numbers (which are in octal, not decimal) are a different notation for the same permission bits. For example, 6 is binary '110' which is 'rw-', and 0 is '---', therefore chmod will also accept `600` for 'rw-------'.

(In Lynis' output, for some odd reason, the "found" permissions are only in octal but the "suggested" permissions are only in text form.)

I'm actually going to say that file permissions are part of "Linux basics 101" and you really ought to know how to handle them *before* you run elaborate security auditing tools on the system – otherwise you won't be able to understand what the auditing tools are telling you.

> Other than adding additional security the relevant files & directories, what, if any, are downsides / possible negative impacts that I need to consider?

First, consider whether there are any tools which *do* need read access to those files, and aren't running with root privileges. (In this case, most likely there aren't any – the cron daemon itself has privileges, nothing else needs to read that file.)

Second, consider whether the audit warning is actually warranted. On most systems, the "system" crontab has nothing sensitive in the first place; that's just where miscellaneous system maintenance tasks go. In fact those files usually contain just the default tasks that are exactly the same as on every other machine running Debian 10.

(Of course, if you have to comply with a security policy that "there must be no security audit warnings" then the latter half doesn't apply.)

Comment: Thanks for answering the "noob" question.  I have used Ubuntu for X years now and never really ran into permissions issues, beyond getting my Wordpress working.  Any specific reference material you would recommend.. Nothing, I have really has provided examples of what I have asked about.  Building my first internet facing web server.

Comment: For any other newbies without formal linux training, I found a very useful site:
https://chmod-calculator.com/